# Access a field of another field that is a trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to port some C++ code to Rust but I'm having some difficulties.

Is there any way of accessing the **widget** field of **Drawables** in the following example?

```
struct Widget {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

trait Drawable {
    fn draw(&self);
    fn update(&mut self);
}

struct Square {
    widget: Widget,
    child: Option<Box<dyn Drawable>>,
}

impl Drawable for Square {
    fn draw(&self) {
        // Draw Square
    }
    fn update(&mut self) {
        // Update Square
        // Access child's widget property
        if let Some(child) = &mut self.child {
            child.widget.x = 10; // Error
        }
    }
}
```

What I have come up with so far is adding a helper function in the Drawable trait to set the size but can't come up with a way of doing it in a way that I won't have to write it for every Drawable implementation.

```
trait Drawable {
    fn draw(&self);
    fn update(&mut self);
    fn set_size(&mut self, x: u32, y: u32) {
        // Somehow set the size of the widget here instead of implementing it in every struct
    }
}
```

Comment: Who says it has a widget, that is, who says it is a `Square`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman then is there a way to specify that a Drawable must have a widget field ?

Comment: You can add an getter to the `Drawable` trait.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman And there is no way of doing that just once in the trait definition? I'm looking for a way of doing it such a way that I won't need to repeatedly rewrite it every time I'm adding another Drawable implementation.

Comment: What you're trying feels a little like forcing OO design on Rust.

Comment: @cafce25 Sadly that's the only way I know how to do things. If you know of a better way of doing this then please tell me. I really wanna figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: Probably factor out the functions that need the widget into a `trait`. Details depend on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a new method to your trait you could also implement `AsRef<Widget>` and/or `AsMut<Widget>` for your structs that contain a `Widget`.

```rust
struct Widget {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

impl AsMut<Widget> for Square {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Widget {
        &mut self.widget
    }
}

trait Drawable: AsMut<Widget> {
    fn draw(&self);
    fn update(&mut self);
    fn set_size(&mut self, x: u32, y: u32) {
        self.as_mut().x = x;
        self.as_mut().y = y;
    }
}

struct Square {
    widget: Widget,
    child: Option<Box<dyn Drawable>>,
}

impl Drawable for Square {
    fn draw(&self) {
        // Draw Square
    }
    fn update(&mut self) {
        // Update Square
        // Access child's widget property
        if let Some(child) = &mut self.child {
            child.as_mut().x = 10;
            // or
            child.set_size(10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little more work than your implementation but has the added benefit that you can reuse it in other traits.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution thanks to Chayim

```
struct Widget {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

trait Drawable {
    fn draw(&self);
    fn update(&mut self);
    fn get_widget(&mut self) -> &mut Widget;
    fn set_size(&mut self, x: u32, y: u32) {
        Drawable::get_widget(self).x = x;
        Drawable::get_widget(self).y = y;
    }
}

struct Square {
    widget: Widget,
    child: Option<Box<dyn Drawable>>,
}

impl Drawable for Square {
    fn draw(&self) {
        // Draw Square
    }
    fn update(&mut self) {
        // Update Square
        // Access child's widget property
        if let Some(child) = &mut self.child {
            child.get_widget().x = 10;
            // or
            child.set_size(10, 10);
        }
    }
    fn get_widget(&mut self) -> &mut Widget {
        return &mut self.widget;
    }
}
```